# Change object data type to float data type

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I read the .cvs file, which dataframe is named "df". But because I want to focus in one row I renamed my dataframe to "br". My problem is that I'm trying to convert the **object** columns that have percentage (Bronx %, Brooklyn%, Manhattan%, Queens%, State Island%) into **float**. How do I change to a **float** data type?

```
df = pd.read_csv('Education.csv')
br = df.loc[[15]]
```

[image: hello]

```
br['Bronx %'].dtype
dtype('O')
```

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use the float() function -

```
my_string = "193.2341412"
my_float = float(my_string)
print(my_float)
>>> 193.2341412
print(type(my_float))
>>> <* FLOAT >
```

Comment: But this won't work for the OP. For starters, the OP is using `pandas`, and the strings have percent signs in them. So the OP needs to clean the data first

Comment: ah - f strings it is - https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/